# Using Azure Quota API for Microsoft.ContainerInstance

Tags: azure, azure-container-instances

I am trying to use the [Azure Quota API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/reserved-vm-instances/quota/create-or-update?tabs=HTTP) to increase the limits of Azure Container Instance. However, it tells me that the provider `Microsoft.ContainerInstance` is invalid. When I use `Microsoft.Compute` the exact same request does work. Anyone an idea how to solve this?

Working request:

https:// management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscription_id>/providers/Microsoft.Capacity/resourceProviders/Microsoft.Compute/locations/westeurope/serviceLimits/StandardDv2Family

Failing request:

https:// management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscription_id>/providers/Microsoft.Capacity/resourceProviders/Microsoft.ContainerInstance/locations/westeurope/serviceLimits/StandardCores

```
Error 400 Bad request
 {
   "error": {
     "code": "BadRequest",
     "message": "The value provided for one of the Provider Ids was not in the correct format. Verify the value of Provider ID : Microsoft.ContainerInstance'."
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure Quota API currently supports only Azure virtual machines (cores/vCPU) and Azure Machine Learning services (dedicated/vCPUs).